# Trying to switch from table design to css and having an issue lining everything up

Tags: css

In the "old days" we could put everything into td cells and everything lined up very nicely. With this css, I'm kind of lost with how to do some things. The issue I am having is that I would like to take the left side text, pad about 50px on the right side and then use an input tag next to the text. What I am getting though is the input boxes are not even depending on the length of the text. If I used a table design, the td tag would have expanded to the longest text and then all of the inputs to the right would line up great. How can I achieve this with css?

---

Here is my html

```
  <li class="mainForm" id="fieldBox_2">
    <label class="formFieldQuestion">Caption: <input class=mainForm type=text name=field_2 id=field_2 size='30' value=''>
      <a class=info href=#><img src=imgs/tip_small.png border=0><span class=infobox>please enter the</span></a>
    </label>
  </li>
```

And the CSS

```
#mainForm 
{
    position: relative;
    border: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
    width: 70%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
ul.mainForm
{
    list-style-type: none;
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size:15px; 
}
li.mainForm
{
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

label.formFieldQuestion
{
    line-height:125%;
    padding:0 4px 1px 0;
    border:none;
    display:block;
    font-size:95%;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: OK, I posted it above. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the input field description in a label tag and assign a fixed width style to the labels.

Comment: Hi Simon, I just posted my css and html above. Would your suggestion work for this?

Comment: I would add a width description to label.formFieldQuestion, like "width: 70px;"

Comment: Thanks Simon. I already tried that and what I noticed was that nothing lined up that way either because the longer text still pushes the input boxes out 70 pixels and the shorter text is pushed out the same distance. It looks exactly the same.

Comment: Well, I just used inline css and pushed out the input boxes as I needed. I'll give you the credit for the answer since you were the only one that offered anything. :)   Thanks.